# Unfollow a path (opposite of ctrl+p)

Tags: shortcut, path

I have an object (text) following a path in an animation, but when I move or size the path the object is resized too.

I would like to edit the path without affecting the object but cant see an "unfollow path" option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the hotkeys for basic commands in blender are structured the same:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Key</kbd> > Command

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Key</kbd> > Inverse of the command

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Key</kbd> > Alternative of the command

In your case to clear the object from the parent is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>